# How to enable iOS Adobe AIR app for TestFlight testing under iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, air, app-store, adobe

Recently I tried to publish my Adobe Air based app for iOS.
I created the neccessary stuff like distribution certificate + provisining profile. Then I packed the app using

```
adt -target ipa-app-store...
```

I uploaded the ipa by using the Application Loader from within OSX virtual machine. I see my app in iTunes Connect account. It's possible to submit the application to the review. But before, I would like to test it.

When I go to

```
iTunes Connect (login)->My Apps->My App->Prerelease->Builds
```

I see the build (ipa) I uploaded. I enabled the TestFlight Beta Testing for the build. I see the notification "To start testing, invite at least one tester."

[image: TestFlight Beta testing enabled]

**The sacral question is how to invite testers?** Because when I go to "Internal Testers" section I see this screen. I see no button "Invite". What I can do is just tick the checkbox and click "Save".

[image: No "Invite" button available]

May be I need to somehow add beta entitlement to the build. But in the provided FAQ (first pic) told that currently created provisining profiles includes this entitlement.

[image: TestFlight entitlement FAQ]

The second question is: 
I can only run app on registred devices that packed either in ipa-debug or ipa-ad-hoc. Will tester be able to run this build ipa (packed with ipa-app-store) after the successfuly invitation?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a post on the subject. See if it helps.

http://www.flashdeveloper.co/post/99200413877/enabling-testflight-testing-in-itunes-connect-for

Comment: Thanks for the link, but you should post the actual answer here as well. Link-only answers are bad answers because links can go down at anytime.

Comment: @OMA aaaaand.... you are right. Link down, but this shows up as accepted answer....

Comment: http://blog.danielalbu.com/post/99200413877/enabling-testflight-testing-in-itunes-connect-for

Comment: Now it's here: https://blog.danielalbu.com/post/99200413877/enabling-testflight-testing-in-itunes-connect-for-adobe

Answer (score 2):

Go to your User section (main menu) and enable some account(s) for internal beta testing. The accounts need to be admin or (?) type to be enabled for internal beta testing.
Now get back to your app (the version you uploaded), open internal test tab and invite testers by checking the box.